# How to fetch 3 rows at the same time with While or For in PHP?

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

For example, I have 30 items.
I use this code to row items one by one:

```
for ($i=1; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
   $cformat = substr($name[$i], -3);
   echo $cformat; echo "<br>";
}
```

There will be 30 strings in the output.
So how to row 3 items at the same time, like this:

```
echo "item 1:" echo $cformat1; echo "<br>";
echo "item 2:" echo $cformat2; echo "<br>";
echo "item 3:" echo $cformat3; echo "<br>";
```

So there will be 10 strings like:

```
item 1: 1.jpg
item 2: 2.jpg
item 3: 3.jpg
----
item 1: 4.jpg
item 2: 5.jpg
item 3: 6.jpg
----
...
```

Comment: modulus http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Just add increment counter variable and reset it if it is 3.

```
$j = 1;
for ($i=1; $i<=(sizeof($name)-1); $i++) {
   $cformat = substr($name[$i], -3);
   echo "item $j: $cformat <br/>";         // counter variable $j is added
   if(++$j>3) $j=1;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter - specify the reason when you downvote a post

Comment: It returns: `Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 72 bytes)`

Comment: @HEISENBERG Sorry updated now! I used increment variable too `$i`, which conflicts with your `for` loop's incrementer

Comment: Thank you very much bro!

Comment: I would upvote, but my reputation is 9, I need 15 :(

Comment: You can upvote answers of your own question without any troubles!

Comment: `Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.` :(